# iOS: How does client reconnect to xmpp server

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am very new in developing im with using ios xmpp.I have some issues waiting to fix.
How can i reconnect xmpp server when client is disconnected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could keep a bool value in NSUserDefaults for checking connection status. Set this bool to true if connection is successful and false whenever disconnecting.

Then check if bool is false, connect it the similar way you were connecting it for the first time.

Hope that answers your question as I am not getting what exactly you want to ask.